# Does UFT (14.xx) supports Relative Path to call the existing API Test from GUI Test

Tags: api, hp-uft, uft-api

Does UFT supports Relative Path to call the existing API Test from GUI Test? Right now I am calling the API test from GUI Action using option (Insert Call to NewAction -> Call to Existing API Test/Action -> Navigate to the directory where API test exists).  Here Test is being added using absolute path.

But Here I would like to use the relative path to call the existing API test. But During the navigate to the directory, If I try to give the relative path (Let's say if API test is present inside the folder APITest inside the GUI test directory, If I provide the relative path as //APITest), it doesn't identify the test present.

Inside the options -> Folder, Current test directory has been already added by default.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An other alternative would be that you compose the path yourself:

```
RunApiTest Environment("TestDir") & "(\..\)rel\path\to\api\test"
```

Environment("TestDir") always contains the full path of the current test be it the FileSystem or HPE ALM